# Getting a 404 not found on mvc controller via ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am getting a 404 not found on a partial view I am trying to load which I am using a controler to decide what is loaded

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetPartialView()
{
  //Add model if any and send it through partialview
  return PartialView("_PartnerDetailsForm.cshtml");
}
```

[image]

Here in my script file is the project of ajax I am using to load the partiview but i am getting a error 404 not found when i debug.

```
$(document).on('change', '#chkisJointApplication', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetPartialView", "FormsController")',
                type: "Get",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#partnerForm").html(data);
                }
            });

        }
        else
            $("#partnerForm").html(''); //clearing the innerHTML if checkbox is unchecked
  });
```

Debug Of Console Window
[image]

Screen shot to show the Forms Controller.
[image]

**Edit 1**
That worked but now I am faced with the following problem, how do

[image]

**Edit 2**

This is to show the form contents of the partial view.

```
<div class="row">

 <section class="col col-6">

     <label class="input">

        <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
    </label>
</section>
<section class="col col-6">
    <label class="input">
        <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
        <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name">
    </label>
</section>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <section class="col col-6">
    <label class="input">
        <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-envelope"></i>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
    </label>
</section>
<section class="col col-6">
    <label class="input">
        <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-phone"></i>
        <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    </label>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you really have a controller named `FormsControllerController`? (assuming its `FormController`, then its  `url: '@Url.Action("GetPartialView", "Forms")',`

Comment: And is that script in an external file? In which case you cannot use `@Url.Action()` - razor code is not parsed in external files

Comment: yes it is then how would i be better using it ?.

Comment: You could add the url to the element with `id="chkisJointApplication"` using `data-url="@Url.Action("GetPartialView", "Forms")"` and then in the function use `var url = $(this).data('url');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you nead fix code js such as:

```
$(document).on('change', '#chkisJointApplication', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Forms/GetPartialView',
                type: "Get",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#partnerForm").html(data);
                }
            });

        }
        else
            $("#partnerForm").html(''); //clearing the innerHTML if checkbox is unchecked
  });
```

Comment: No, you call '@Url.Action("GetPartialView", "FormsController")' in js file, it will not working

Comment: This worked but one question the containing div is not increasing its size to the height of the partial view anyway around this.

Comment: You can to try using $("#partnerForm").append(data);

Comment: That didnt incrases the size of div :-(

Comment: are you can for me see code your from "_PartnerDetailsForm"?

Comment: Just to clarify it better, you can't use Razor syntax in a .js file because Razor commands aren't parsed there. You have to provide a regular URL path to the ActionMethod in the the Controller. Leave the ending "Controller" part out of the Controller name in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to write the word 'controller'....this would do:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetPartialView", "Forms")'
```

**EDIT**

In case you have it in .js file:

put this in the view:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myUrl" value = "@Url.Action("GetPartialView", "Forms")" />
```

and in js:

```
url: $("#myUrl").val(),
```

or

```
url: document.getElementById('myUrl').value,
```

Comment: As Linh pointed out im using this in script.js and it does not understand razor syntax how would i right it in that case

Comment: @yoda77ni use `url: '/Forms/GetPartialView',` instead of that, so whats your problem?